# Passing parameters between html and spyder python

Tags: python, html, ajax, parameter-passing, spyder

I have a project where I am trying to pass parameters from html (front end) using ajax to the python code (spyder). After this the python will process the data and return some values.
I was wondering if passing of parameters is possible. If yes then how? 
I tried using url="name of python.py"
Post
Please do not mind if the question is really basic. I am new to python and have very little experience in it.